# The text inside the Toolbar is not centered

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar

I've written the following code in `XML`. But the `RelativeLayout` does not fit into the `Toolbar` completely and is about 10dp from the left.

Codes of `XML`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/supporter"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/yekan"
    android:text="@string/appnameForUsers"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/supporter"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Try to set `android:label=""` in the AndroidManifest.xml or `setTitle("")` programmatically in the activity.

Comment: you can basically change  android:background="@color/colorAccent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

add this attribute in your Toolbar

Comment: The answer was short and very useful. really thank you

Comment: @Reza anytime friend..Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove default padding from `ToolBar`

use below code in `ToolBar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  .............
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"

app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
.................
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell to your TextView to move text to left/start and make it to use entire space. If si not desired, move it to left.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a tag `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` to remove the default padding from left side in `Toolbar`.

You can also add other tags like `app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"` if you're getting padding to the right, but in your case, it is not needed.

You'll have to add this tag to your `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with below snippet of code. It'll solve your problem.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_1"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/supporter" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/appnameForUsers"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_2"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/supporter" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Do not solve my problem. My problem is with Toolbar. RelativeLayout is not set to the  size as the entire Toolbar. Can I send a picture of it?

Comment: @Reza send your requirement pic